# OrderBy row with same string but different uiid and position in another table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm using SQL with [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) with [Symfony 4.4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) with simple sql query like:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.address a WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

My problem is
I have two tables:

```
Table A
[UIID name]

Table B
[UIID] is a reference key of UIID table A
```

For instance (for more simplicity in the example the UIID is an int):

```
A
1 Alpha
2 Alpha
3 Beta
4 Charlie
5 Delta
6 Delta


B
2
```

I like to do this:

```
SELECT UIID NAME
FROM A
GROUP BY UIID,
ORDER BY NAME
```

But to have before the element present also in the table B and after the elments present only the table A:

```
2 Alpha
1 Alpha
3 Beta
4 Charlie
5 Delta
6 Delta
```

I know that there is a difference between uiid v1 and others version of timestamp position.
I cannot modify the id of the database so I ask myself if there is an instruction like `LIKE` for doing it without to create a new table with the ID and timestamp.

ps:
I have had a mistake before:
I have written:

```
SELECT UIID NAME
FROM A
GROUP BY UIID,
ORDER BY UIID
```

But in I wished to say:

```
SELECT UIID NAME
FROM A
GROUP BY UIID,
ORDER BY NAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `LEFT` join of the tables:

```
SELECT A.UIID, A.name
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON B.UIID = A.UIID
ORDER BY B.UIID IS NULL, A.NAME
```

The expression:

```
B.UIID IS NULL
```

evaluates to `0` or `1` for `false` or `true`, so all the matching rows of the 2 tables will be at the top.

Or with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.UIID, A.name
FROM A
ORDER BY EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.UIID = A.UIID) DESC, 
         A.NAME
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7ecd07ea913b47aa76f378dc4998091e).
Results:

```
| UIID | name    |
| ---- | ------- |
| 2    | Alpha   |
| 1    | Alpha   |
| 3    | Beta    |
| 4    | Charlie |
| 5    | Delta   |
| 6    | Delta   |
```

Comment: Thanks and I need to order by name (I have commited a mistake in the question)?
SELECT UIID NAME
FROM A
GROUP BY UIID,
ORDER BY NAME